# What is the law of the ratio of two independent gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How calculate the probability density function of $Z = X_1/X_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77873/how-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-z-x-1-x-2)
> [The probability density function of the ratio of two normal R.V.s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79583/the-probability-density-function-of-the-ratio-of-two-normal-r-v-s)

Consider two independent randon variables $N , N' \sim \mathcal N (0,1)$.What is the law of $N/N'$ ?

Comment: Here is the first hit on Google for "ratio of Gaussian random variables": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution. Your answer is in the second paragraph, it is a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Just to amplify on Rahul's comment - the Cauchy distribution is a  power law. If I remember it doesn't even have a convergent mean, certainly no variance. This long-tail behavior is intuitive if you think of the denominator often being close to zero ($\sim \mathcal N (0,1)$).

Comment: An unrelated way to obtain a Cauchy distribution is via Gull's "Lighthouse" problem from 1988: http://www.gps.caltech.edu/classes/ge193/practicals/practical3/Lighthouse.pdf

Comment: Answers on _this_ website can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77873/15941) as well as in many other questions (see for example, Didier's comment on the question).

Comment: @alancalvitti That, or the first hitting place of a given hyperplane by a Brownian particle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $(N,N')$ in polar coordinates as $(R,\Theta)$.  Their joint distribution becomes $$\text{constant}\cdot e^{-r^2/2} r\,dr\,d\theta.\tag{1}$$ From $(1)$ we see that $R$, $\Theta$ are independent and $\Theta$ is uniformly distributed in $\mathbb R\bmod 2\pi$.  The ratio $N/N'$ is $\tan\Theta$.  Since $\tan$ has period one-half of a circle, nothing is lost by taking $\Theta$ to be in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\Pr(\tan\Theta\le\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta}\Pr(\Theta\le \arctan\theta) = \frac{d}{d\theta} \frac{\arctan\theta}{\pi} = \frac{1/\pi}{1+\theta^2}.
$$