# Find absolate value and division of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I am looking for at hint solve this:

$X_1, X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Find the distribution of $\frac{X_1+X_2}{|X_1-X_2|}$

I have gotten so far that $X_1+X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$ and $X_1-X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2)$

But I have no idea how to handle the absolute and division

Comment: Hint: Note also that $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 - X_2$ are independent.

Comment: Assuming $X_1,X_2$ are independent, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161566/321264), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79583/321264) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948527/321264) should answer your question alongwith the hint above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: represent graphically $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{x+y}{|x-y|}\}$ and study how to calculate the integral in the area: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \frac{x+y}{|x-y|} \leq t\}=F_Z(z)$. Then you can derivate $F_Z(z)$ (where it is possible) to get what you want (i.e. the distribution of $Z=\frac{X_1+X_2}{|X_1-X_2|}$).

It can be usefull to compute also the joint distribution.

Answer (score 1):

By [#Correlations_and_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence), $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$ are independent.  As @StubbornAtom mentioned,By [distribution of $\frac{X}{|Y|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161566/find-the-distribution-of-frac-xy-given-that-x-and-y-are-independent)

$$ \frac{\frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt{2}}}{\frac{\mid X_1-X_2 \mid}{\sqrt{2}}}\sim Cauchy(0,1)$$