# Joint Density of $\sin(2\pi U)$ and $\cos(2\pi U)$,$ U$ uniform $(0,1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need help with finding the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ where
$$X=\sin(2\pi U),\quad Y=\cos(2\pi U)$$
where $U$ is uniformly distributed on (0,1).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/absolute-continuity-of-a-distribution-function?rq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(X,Y)$ is almost surely on the unit circle whose Lebesgue measure is zero, the distribution of $(X,Y)$ has no density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the plane $\mathbb R^2$.

To describe the distribution of $(X,Y)$ one usually says that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit circle, which is another way of saying that, for every measurable function $a$ on $\mathbb R^2$,
$$
E(a(X,Y))=\int_0^{2\pi}a(\cos t,\sin t)\frac{\mathrm dt}{2\pi}.
$$

Comment: Thanks Did. Does it have a joint cdf at least?

Comment: Every pair of random variables has a CDF. The CDF of (X,Y) is a mess (and quite uninteresting).