# Division of two independent uniformly random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Given two independent random variable X and Y which both have uniform distribution over[0,1] I want to calculate PDF of $Z =\frac{X}{Y}$ and here is my solution:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zf_X(yz)f_Y(y)dy = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{z}}zdy = 1$
is this correct?
one thing i am in doubt is the main relation that I have found over the internet:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zf_X(yz)f_Y(y)dy$
is this correct?

Comment: You have to be more careful with limits of integration. For example, if $z<1$ then you won't be integrating up to $\frac 1 z$ because that goes beyond $(0,1)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $0 \leq YZ \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq Y \leq \frac{1}{Z}$ is this wrong?

Comment: But you cannot forget the extra condition $Y\leq 1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so what should i do?

Comment: If $z<1$ you have to integrate from $0$ to $1$, not $0$ to $1/z$.

Comment: Do these posts help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/pdf-of-a-quotient-of-uniform-random-variables, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285127/using-cdf-to-calculate-ratio-of-two-uniformly-distributed-random-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15522/distribution-of-a-ratio-of-uniforms-what-is-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?