# Find pdf of transformation of two random variables using CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> Let $X,Y \sim$ Uniform$(0,1)$ be independent. Find the PDF for $X/Y$.

Let $Z=X/Y$. We want to find $F_z(z)=P(Z \leq z)=P(X/Y \leq z)$.

We can make $Y$ super small with fixed $X$, and conversely we can make $X$ really small with fixed $Y$. Thus it appears to me that we have $0<z<\infty$.  I am struggling to find the subgraph of the unit square. We know that $X \leq Yz$. If $z = 1$, then we have a simple diagonal through the unit square. Increasing the value of $z$ shrinks what $Y$ can be since $X$ must be between $0$ and $1$. So we should see these lines fan out below the diagonal of the square as $z$ increases. Conversely, if $z$ approaches $0$, then we we limit the range of $X$, and so these lines fan out above the diagonal.

What I am having trouble with is putting this all together and calculating the integral itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pdf of a quotient of uniform random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113295/pdf-of-a-quotient-of-uniform-random-variables) Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15522/119261.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F_Z(z)=P[\frac{X}{Y} \leq z]=P[Y \geq \frac{X}{z}]$$

Drawing the  line $Y=\frac{X}{z}$ in the unit square you see that CDF(z) is the area above this line thus

$$F_Z(z) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $z<0$} \\
\frac{z}{2},  & \text{if $0\leq z<1$} \\
1-\frac{1}{2z}, & \text{if $z \geq 1$}
\end{cases}$$

To get PDF(z) just derivate F

Not any integral is needed. All the calculations can be done evaluating  triangles' areas.