# Find the density function of the random variable $Z=X+Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent and uniformly distributed random variable on the intervals $[0,3]$ and $[0,1]$, respectively. Find the density function of the random variable $Z=X+Y$.

I find $f(x,y)=1/3$ and the range of $Z$ to be $[0,4]$, but I cannot find the density function of $Z$.

Comment: Find $P\{Z \leq \alpha\}$ for $\alpha \in [0,1]$, for $\alpha \in (1,3)$, and $\alpha \in [3,4]$. Then differentiate with respect to $\alpha$ to find the density function.  Look, for example, at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250431/15941) and its answers for ideas on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

Another way, if you are confortable with [convolutions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html), is to recall that the sum of independent variables has a density that is the convolution of the components. In this case, we must convolve a unit rectangle with a rectangle in $[0,3]$, which is very similar to this 
image (except for some axis shifting and scaling) (in our case we'd have $f_X$ in red, $f_Y$ in blue, and the result in green), and which results in the function given in Calvin's answer.

[image]

Comment: When one realizes that the result of the convolution is a trapezoid whose base is of length $4$ and the "top" (the side parallel to the base) is of length $2$, very little additional calculation is required. The area of the trapezoid is $$\frac{1}{2}\times(4+2)\times(\text{distance between parallel sides})$$ and since the area must be $1$, we have that $f_Z(z)$ increases linearly from $0$ to $\frac{1}{3}$ as $z$ increases from $0$ to $1$, has constant value $\frac{1}{3}$ for $z\in[1,3]$ and decreases linearly to $0$ as $z$ increases from $3$ to $4$; additional details as in Calvin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, to find the pdf, you should find the cdf first, and then differentiate the function.

$F[z] = P(Z \leq z)  = \begin{cases} \frac {1}{6} z^2 & 0\leq z \leq 1 \\ 
\frac {1}{6} + \frac {1}{3} (x-1) & 1 \leq z \leq 3 \\
1- \frac {1}{6} (4-z)^2 & 3 \leq z \leq 4 \\ \end{cases}$

This gives that

$f(z) = \begin{cases} \frac {1}{3} z & 0 \leq z \leq 1 \\ \frac {1}{3}  & 1 \leq z \leq 3 \\ \frac {1}{3} (4-z) & 3 \leq z \leq 4 \\\ \end{cases}$

Comment: The "hard" part of this problem is determining the CDF and perhaps you could provide some hints to the OP as to how to go about doing that.