# Find density functions of $Z=X+Y$ when the joint density function is known.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find the density function of $Z=X+Y$, $X$, $Y$ where the joint density function of $(X,Y)$ is given by $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} (x+y) e^{-(x+y)},\, x,y \geq 0$.

My initial idea is to calculate the distribution function of $Z$ like this:

$P(Z < z) = P(X+Y < z) = P(X < z-Y)$

$F_{z} = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits^{z}_{0}\int\limits^{z-y}_{0} (x+y) e^{-(x+y)} dx\, dy$

and then calculate its derivative $F_{z}^{'}$

Is this the way to go ?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. But notice that you are computing a double integral and then differentiating the result to get the density. Since "differentiation undoes integration" it is possible to combine the two steps and compute the density using just one integration. The resulting single integral is shown in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/250458/15941) to a related problem.

Comment: I noticed that, but I am unable get those densities $f_x, f_y$ such that $f(x,y) = f_x(x) \cdot f_y(y)$

Comment: Err... you should have stopped reading my answer at the point where it said $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) &= \cdots\\&=\cdots\\&\vdots\\&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\,\mathrm dx\end{align}$$ which applies to _all_ random variables, not just to independent random variables.

Comment: ok, with the hint it becomes

\begin{array}[rl]{l}
f_{X+Y}(z) &= \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{z} (x+z-x)\, e^{-(x+z-x)}\, dx \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{z} z\, e^{-z}\, dx \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} z\cdot e^{-z} \int\limits_{0}^{z} \, dx \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} z^2\,e^{-z} \\
\end{array}

Comment: See? Wasn't that a lot easier? I recommend that you write up your solution, including the way you got to the simple calculation, and post it as an answer to your own problem. After a while, you could even accept your own answer as the best of all the answers if you like. By the way, such actions are not just acceptable but also an approved way of proceeding in such cases.

Comment: far easier, thanks for your patience

Comment: Also, the original integration mentioned in jed's answer would give you the marginal probability not the cdf. if not why? thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Joint density is $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} (x+y) e^{-(x+y)},\, x,y \geq 0$ and the distribution function is

$F_Z(z) = P(Z < z) = P (X+Y < z) = P ( X < z, Y < z - X)$

then we have for the density of Z

\begin{array}[rl]{l}
f_{Z}(z) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z} F_z(z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int\limits_{0}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{z-x} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx \\
         &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z} F_z(z) =  \int\limits_{0}^{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int\limits_{0}^{x-z} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx \\
         &=   \int\limits_{0}^{z} f(x,z-x)\cdot 1 - f(x,0)\cdot 0 \,dx \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{0}^{z} z\, e^{-z}\, dx \\
           &= \frac{1}{2} z\cdot e^{-z} \int\limits_{0}^{z} \, dx \\
f_{Z}(z) &= \frac{1}{2} z^2\,e^{-z} \\
\end{array}

Comment: I think there may be some typos such as $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and the third line really should resolve to the integral of $f(x,z-x)$ and not of $f(x,x-z)$ the way you have it.