# Why is P(X+Y<z)=P(X<z,Y<X−z)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As indicated by the title I'm not sure why the following holds

$P(X+Y<z) = P(X<z, Y<z-X)$?

Comment: I think that should read $P(X+Y<z) = P(X<z, Y<z-X)$... and then it is clear that the right-hand-side is just a redundant way of saying $P(X+Y<z)$ since $X+Y<z$ is just an algebraic manipulation of $Y<z-X$.

Comment: right. but then why does it become and intersecting probability?

Comment: Actually I think it only holds if $X$, $Y$, and $z$ are positive

Comment: That is the only case where the $X<z$ part of the event becomes redundant. I.e. if they are all positive, then $X<z$ is already implied by $Y < z - X$ or equivalently $X+Y<z$.

Comment: ok so i was trying to avoid giving context because I was looking for some deeper general understanding. But this equation reference is from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373365/find-density-for-z-xy-with-joint-density-function

Comment: Yes in that question $X, Y > 0$. Be sure to include necessary details in your questions; as it was posed here, the claim was false. To answer you for the case that $X, Y > 0$, just think about how if $X + Y < z$ then both $X<z$ and $Y<z$ must hold. I can even say $P(X+Y < z) = P(X<z, Y<z, X+Y<z)$.

Comment: oh ok. that make sense. Sorry - I wasn't sure what was relevant and what wasn't. Thanks jnez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not *always* hold, however, it is true whenever $Y$ is certainly non-negative (and so is $z$).

$\{(X,Y)\in\Bbb R^2:X+Y< z\} = \{(X,Y)\in\Bbb R^2:X<z-Y, Y<z-X\}$ is always so.   It is just algebraic rearrangement and redundancy.

When $Y$ is certainly non-negative and $X+Y< z$, then we can be sure that at least $X<z$, and push responsibility for fully constraining outcomes onto the redundant criteria.

$$\{(X,Y)\in\Bbb R_+^2:X+Y< z\} = \{(X,Y)\in\Bbb R_+^2:X<z, Y<z-X\}$$

Since they describe the same event, they have the same probability.

$$\mathsf P(X+Y<z) ~=~ \mathsf P(X<z, Y<z-X)\qquad\text{iff }\{Y<0\}=\emptyset$$

Comment: Thanks Graham! this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=100$, $y=-100$, $z=1$ then $$x+y=0<1=z$$ but $$x=100\not < 1=z$$

even if

$$y=-100<z-x=-99.$$

That is, the statement at stake is not true.