# Sum of Independent Folded-Normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, normally distributed random variables.

How is $|X| + |Y|$ distributed?

Is it known to be $|Z|$, where $Z$ is distributed normally?

Comment: Yuck. I ... doubt it.

Comment: Identical variances for $X$ and $Y$? Or different? Zero means? Or different?

Comment: There is a problem with the title:$$Sum.of.Independent.Half Normal.distributions$$
If $X$~$N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $|X|$ has a folded Normal distribution (not a half-Normal (unless $\mu = 0$)). Accordingly, the question is actually seeking the sum of independent folded Normals … not the sum of independent half-Normals.

Comment: Okay thanks I fixed it

Comment: @wolfies : There's such a thing as \text{} within MathJax: $$\text{Sum of Independent Half-Normal distributions}$$

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For $\alpha > 0$,
$$F_{|X|+|Y|}(\alpha) = P\{|X|+|Y|\leq \alpha\} 
= P\{(X,Y) \in A\}$$
where $A$ is a square region with vertices $(\alpha,0), (0,\alpha), (-\alpha, 0), (0,-\alpha)$.

- Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have $0$ mean and identical variance $\sigma^2$. Then,
  since the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ has circular symmetry, we can rotate
  the square about the origin so that the sides are parallel to the axes and at distance
  $\alpha/\sqrt{2}$ from them.  Consequently,
  \begin{align}F_{|X|+|Y|}(\alpha) &= P\{(X,Y) \in A\}\\
  &= \left[\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
  - \Phi\left(\frac{-\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)\right]^2\\
  &= \left[2\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)
  - 1\right]^2.
  \end{align}
  Can you get the density of $Z$ from this? (Hint: think of the chain
  rule for differentiation from basic calculus, and remember that you know
  the derivative of $\Phi(x)$)  Note that $Z$ is *not* the absolute value of
  a normal random variable.
- More generally, for arbitrary independent normal random variables, we have that
  \begin{align}
  F_{|X|+|Y|}(\alpha) &= P\{(X,Y) \in A\}\\
  &= \int_{-\alpha}^0\int_{-\alpha-x}^{\alpha+x}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy \mathrm dx
  + \int_0^{\alpha}\int_{x-\alpha}^{-x+\alpha}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx.
  \end{align}
  Rather than computing the integrals and then differentiating with respect to
  $\alpha$ to find the density of $|X|+|Y|$, one can directly differentiate the integrals
  with respect to $\alpha$.  If you don't remember the details of how to do so,
  see the comment following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77906/15941)
  and remember that when you are differentiating the outer integral (the one with
  respect to $x$), the integrand (a.k.a. the value of the inner integral)
  is also a function of $\alpha$.

Comment: Wow that's a cool use of symmetry!

Comment: Verrrry nice...

Comment: Could you please make clearer what the function Φ is?

Comment: @Cemre $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative probability distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal random variable.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Maybe you're *the* person to have an idea for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1634307/maximum-of-a-sum-of-random-variables...

Comment: @DilipSarwate What's the name of the distribution of $|X|+|Y|$ when $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathcal{N}(μ,σ)$ ? Looks like a LogNormal, but it's not, see [this plot](http://gget.it/lsm9itc2/abs(X1)+abs(X2),normaldistribution.jpg). What's it's name?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hi there, I'm wondering the same. When I do your calculation I get that the density is something like $2(2*cdf(\alpha/(\sqrt{2}\sigma))-1)*2*pdf(\alpha/(\sqrt{2}\sigma))/\sqrt{2}/\sigma)$ but numerically that does not seem to hold true. Could you please point me to my mistake?

Comment: @Jonasson What you have written seems correct but what do you mean that the result does not seem to hold true numerically? Are you saying that the area under the curve is not $1$? That the function is negative somewhere? You _are_ aware that the expression is valid only for $\alpha \geq 0$, right?

Comment: Dear Dilip. Thank you very much for your quick reply. What I did was to draw and add 1000 samples from each of two (independent) folded normal distributions using scipy and then plot their distribution alongside the above pdf but the results don't overlap. If you are curios I can send you an .ipynb. Please allow me a further questions: Is it correct to say that folded normals have subgaussian tails? I am asking because I would like to use concentration results (like Hoeffdings inequality) on the sum of many iid folded normals. Thank you for your consideration!

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hi! I haven't quite understood the point about circular symmetry. Could you please kindly elaborate, why can we just use the rotated square instead of the original one?

Comment: @Swistack Circular symmetry means the joint pdf looks the same and has the same formula if the _axes_ are rotated by any arbitrary angle $\theta$. So rotate the axes by $\pi/4$ which makes the sides of the square parallel to the axes.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you!