# Sum of folded normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Set three random variables

\begin{equation*}
X_1, X_2, X_3 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)
\end{equation*}

and their respective transformations

\begin{equation*}
Y_1 = |X_1| \;,\; Y_2=|X_2| \;,\; Y_3= |X_3|. 
\end{equation*}

I know the densities for each $Y$s but I would like to find the distribution of

\begin{equation*}
Z=Y_1+Y_2+Y_3. 
\end{equation*}

I saw an answer for two folded normals and I wasn't sure how to transpose it to my problem.

Comment: Where have you seen the answer ?

Comment: Don't know how to use links here but here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/428790