# Difference of Independent Folded-Normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $Z \sim N(\mu,1)$, $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(0,1)$ be independent random variables.

By definition, the absolute value of a Normal random variable is said to have a folded Normal distribution.

I'm trying to find:  $\; P(|Z| >|Y|) \;$ and $ \; P(|Z| >|X|)$.

Also, I'm trying to find, for the function: $\max[|Z|, |Y|, |X| ]$, 
what is the probability that |Z| is the max value of the three?

Reference also:  [Sum of Independent Folded-Normal distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428781/sum-of-independent-folded-normal-distributions)

Comment: Welcome, please [edit] the post to add a link to the question you're referring to and use [MathJax](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to type in mathematics.

Comment: (a) You need to define what $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are - not sufficient to say half-folded --- you need to specify what parameters are included, if any.  And this should be stated at the start - not at the end.  (b) Probability that $Z$ has max value or that $|Z|$ has max value? (c) If some of your variables are folded Normals, then you don't need to take the absolute value, since the folding does that already. So you need to think about your notation.

Comment: I updated my question based on your comments. Thanks

Comment: They don't have the same distribution, only y and x

Comment: Why do you need to find  $\; P(|Z| >|Y|) \;$  and $\; P(|Z| >|X|) \;$  ... if $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?

Comment: O.k. they are equal. then I can find the probability of |Z| is more than |X| and |Y|, i.e. P(|Z|>|Y|) * P(|Z|>|X|)