# Sum of folded normals with equal mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose we have $X,Y,Z$ independent and normally distributed variables, each with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Can we calculate the distribution of $Z = |X| + |Y| + |Z|$? A partial result is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428781/sum-of-independent-folded-normal-distributions?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I'm unsure how to extend this beyond $n>2$.