# Continuous RV - minimizing absolute deviation

Tags: integration, estimation

We try to find c value minimizing E[|x-c|], "expected value of absolute deviations", for a continuous random variable X.

E[|x-c|]=Integral(-inf,inf)[|x-c|]f(x)dx
=Integral(-inf,c)[-x+c]f(x)dx+Integral(c,inf)[x-c]f(x)dx

Now I want to take first derivative here, with respect to c and set it equal to 0. I know I should use the rule "If you integrate a function f and then differentiate the integral with respect to its upper endpoint (y above) you get f back again" but I think I miss the trick.

How can I proceed?

Best regards..

Comment: Your equation defining $E[|X-c|]$ is incorrect. Once you have that fixed, bear in mind that your differentiation needs to take into account that $c$ appears in the integrand as well as in the limit.  If you have forgotten this formula, see, for example, a comment following [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/77906/15941).

Comment: I forgot to write f(x) in the integral.
What I mean is:
from -inf to c, integrate (-x+c)f(x) first.. then from c to inf, integrate (x-c)f(x).. What is wrong about it?

Comment: Your formula is correct _now_

Comment: Every median solves this.

Comment: I know median solves this - but I am trying to prove it.. Basically what will happen is I end up with F(c)-(1-F(c))=0. Then I will show that minimizing c has the property of F(c)=0.5, which is the median.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I wonder how you take this integral. For example,  for Integral(-inf,c) [cf(x)]dx.. What is the derivative of this with respect to c?

Comment: It is not necessary to compute the value of the integral (which value is a function of $c$) before differentiating with respect to $c$. As to what the derivative is, did you try the link I referred you to in my first comment?

Comment: Yes I miswrote again, then edited the comment:) I checked that, but I am not sure about the infinity - I am just confused.

Comment: Ok I got the part with an upper bound c.. But what happens when the upper bound is infinity? Which rule am I supposed to use?

Comment: I guess when upper part is infinity, derivative of integral(xf(x)dx) is 0. and derivative of integral (cf(x)dx) is equal to c*0 + 1*integral(c,inf)[xf(x)]dx. 
Thanks all