# Division of 2 independent variables with Normal Distribution - mean, stdDev, confidence interval?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Given 2 independent variables, A and B, each following its own Normal Distribution (different means, stdDevs and correlation = 0).

What can be inferred about the division of A by B (`A / B`)?

Is the "mean" the division of the means of each variable?

Is it possible to have a standard deviation, or at least define a 95% confidence interval?

Comment: Take a simpler case when $A$ and $B$ are independent standard normal random variables, and read the answers to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/77873/15941). $A/B$ in the case has a Cauchy distribution for which the mean is undefined.

Comment: And in non-standard case $E|1/B|=+\infty$ too, so the mean of $A/B$ does not exist.