# What distribution does $X/Y$ have if $X$ and $Y$ are normal distributed independent variables?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$ iid. What distribution would the variable $\frac{X}{Y}$ follow? Intuitively it would have an expected value of $1$. Or would it?

Comment: It's a Cauchy distribution, which has no well-defined mean:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77873/how-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-z-x-1-x-2?noredirect=1&lq=1.