# CDF of ratio of independent standard normal distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Question; Given two independent standard normally distributed random variables $X,Y,$ find the cumulative density function of $\frac{X}{Y}.$

My attempt:

Note that 
\begin{align*}
F(x) & = P(\frac{X}{Y}\leq x) \\
& = P(\frac{X}{Y}\leq x | Y >0)P(Y>0) + P(\frac{X}{Y}\leq x | Y<0) P(Y<0) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \left[ P(X\leq xY | Y >0) + P(X\geq xY | Y<0) \right].
\end{align*}
However, I have trouble evaluating $P(X\leq xY | Y >0).$

I know the final answer is that the distribution of $\frac{X}{Y}$ is Cauchy. I am trying to prove it by considering CDF and then differentiating CDF to obtain PDF.

Comment: The region $y \leq xz,z>0$ in the $(y,z)$ plane can be nicely described as a polar region (involving the angle $\arctan(1/x)$) which enables you to calculate the associated probability by direct integration in a manner very similar to how the Gaussian integral is normally evaluated.

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate it? Actually I always have difficult evaluating probability involving at two random variables.

Comment: Do you know how the Gaussian integral is evaluated? It is pretty much exactly like that, only with different $\theta$ bounds.

Comment: Yes, one can use polar coordinate to evaluate the gaussian integral.

Comment: See [Quotient of two random variables](https://math.tntech.edu/machida/ISR_GO/Introduction_to_Probability/Distributions_of_Functions/thispage/node16.html) for finishing this calculation. When both means are zero the result is the Cauchy distribution, see also [ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation) more generally.

Comment: I meant this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77873/how-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-z-x-1-x-2?noredirect=1&lq=1.